# Updating data Android

Tags: android, database, webserver, google-cloud-messaging

I want to develop an application that will need its data to be updated regularly, to do that I will add an administrator. I was thinking to make a website for the admin only who will go and update the data over there and then a notification will be sent from the server to the android application using GCM when there is an update, the app will sync and the data will be updated.

Now since I will need to use a server that means my database will be MySQL right?

Or is there another way to do the same thing but without having a headache of using MySQL and json?

I don't have a server of my own, I was going to use a local server like xamp or wamp and I am more used to working sqlite, if there is a solution to get around this problem with sqlite it would be a pleasure to know it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application you are talking about can be achieved by using JSON. For that you need to make api with the related data.

Comment: ok than the database will it be MySQL or SQLite? and how can I make the API? I am sorry if I seem stupid but I am just a beginner

Comment: If you make this application with SQLite or MySQL, then you need to update your database daily via eclipse. i.e. you need to push the update SQLite file in eclipse which won't be feasible. API's will be the best method but API can be built using php. but for starting, there is a lot of free API's available.